# How to get class of T from Vector<T> in java

Tags: java, generics, methods

I wrote this code:

```
public static <T> void getList(Vector<T> result){
    System.out.println(result.getClass().getName());
}
```

I want to write the class name of `T`, but I can't get it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I know you can't. Java generics use type erasure, so at runtime a `Vector<T>` behaves just like a `Vector` without any template arguments.

What you can do instead is query the type of an element of your vector.

Here's a short description of type erasure:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

See also the answers to this question:
[Java generics - type erasure - when and what happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

In other words:

```
void someMethod(Vector<T> values) {
    T value = values.get(0);
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
void someMethod(Vector values) {
    T value = (T) values.get(0);
}
```

at runtime but with some compile time checks for the type you are casting to.